# Scripting dockutil

Tags: shell-script

What am I doing wrong?

I try to configure the dock with a shell script containing dockutil commands.
it works without problems for System Preferences, Safari, TextEdit,
Applications and `~/Downloads`.

However App Store as well `~/Documents` wont be attached...

If the commandos for App Store and `~/Document` are given directly in the terminal the problem does not occur.

Does anyone have an Idea?

```
#!/bin/bash

#
# set Dock items
#

dockutil=/usr/local/bin/dockutil    
$dockutil --remove all --allhomes
$dockutil --add '/Applications/System Preferences.app' --allhomes
$dockutil --add '/Applications/App Store.app' --allhomes
$dockutil --add '/Applications/Safari.app' --allhomes
$dockutil --add '/Applications/TextEdit.app' --allhomes
$dockutil --add '/Applications' --allhomes
$dockutil --add '~/Downloads' --allhomes
$dockutil --add '~/Documents' --allhomes

exit 0
```

Comment: Wouldn't dockutil be already in your path? Why are you setting up a variable for it?

Comment: you are right there is no need for a variable, but after removing it, it works exactly the same.